# Extrude rectangular area from face

Tags: modeling

I have this shape from whose top face I would like to extrude a rectangular area of 5 by 5 mm, as I have expertly illustrated here:

[image: screenshot with drawing]

How would I go about this?

Comment: I would create an open rectangle of the 5mm by 5mm and the then use the Knife Project to create those cut on the Mesh. Then you can just extrude from the result. Knife Project works on your view, so make sure you are in orthographic.

Comment: @rob Knife Project works!